# Can I migrate Sharepoint 2007 lists to Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

Does anybody know an easy way to migrate a Sharepoint 2007 list to Sharepoint 2010 - including column names and the links etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily do this using sharepoint list template. If you need to learn basics of list template see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YVV7UTeELU) video.
To migrate list from 2007 to 2010 using list template, read [this](http://tom-dw.blogspot.com.au/2010/06/importing-sharepoint-2007-list.html) article

Answer (score 0):

There are several tool in market. You have to buy tool and migrate these content and column name to sharepoint 2010. These tool also maintain security and many meta data. If you have question then feel free and contact me